# DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Class not registered [0x80131500]

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

When attempting to deploy ARM to windows phone device via USB in

Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2 (Xamarin UWP/Android App) I am getting this error:

```
DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Class not registered [0x80131500]
```

After a clean install of Windows 16299 I continue to get the error, even with a blank app.  Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem does not happen on Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4.5
(File Version 15.4.27004.2010).

This version was tested on a clean install of Windows 16299 with a 
blank app and also a  working project.
Direct deploy of ARM to Device via USB was successful without issues.

I will continue to use 15.4.5 until the problem with 15.5.2 is resolved.

12/20/2017 EDIT:
as of this date, in an update from 15.4.5 to 15.5.2 the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2017 15.5.6. Solved with:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86\SirepClient.dll"
```

from admin command prompt.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 1706 16299.309 Visualstudio 15.6.4 Thx!